TypeError Reflect.getMetadata error, how I solve this?
Well, I have an error that I can't solve, a reflect metadata error, but I've already done what I could, I've already installed several versions but I get the same error.
my package.json
{
  "name": "inux",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"apps/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/apps/inux/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./apps/inux/test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm --dataSource ./dist/apps/savon/src/db/data-source-cli.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.3.10",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.2",
    "amqplib": "^0.10.4",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cache-manager": "^5.7.4",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "pg": "^8.12.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.14",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.2.2",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.4.2",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.2.3",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.1.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.3.10",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.13",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "serverless": "^3.39.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^13.6.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/apps/",
      "<rootDir>/libs/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@app/livraria(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/libs/livraria/src/$1"
    }
  }
}


I also added import 'reflect-metadata' in the spec.ts files and it didn't work either.
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Hello World!');
  });
});

when I try docker-compose up --build or just up, start to compile but I get a error:
savon-1           | [Nest] 28  - 07/29/2024, 4:19:39 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
savon-1           | [Nest] 28  - 07/29/2024, 4:19:39 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] 
savon-1           | TypeError
savon-1           |     at Reflect.getMetadata (/usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:367:23)
savon-1           |     at DependenciesScanner.isInjectable (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:396:26)
savon-1           |     at DependenciesScanner.insertModule (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:89:18)
savon-1           |     at DependenciesScanner.insertOrOverrideModule (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:306:21)
savon-1           |     at DependenciesScanner.scanForModules (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:37:85)
savon-1           |     at DependenciesScanner.scanForModules (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:68:43)
savon-1           |     at async DependenciesScanner.scan (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:27:9)
savon-1           |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:107:17
savon-1           |     at async ExceptionsZone.asyncRun (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:22:13)
savon-1           |     at async NestFactoryStatic.initialize (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:106:13)


Docker Compose:
version: '3.5'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    env_file:
      - .env

  savon:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/savon/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev savon

  inux:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/inux/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '4000:5000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - savon
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run start:dev inux

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  postgres_admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '15432:80'


DockerFile :(I have 2 app in my nestjs application, both use the same dockerfile configuration)
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

someone have the solution and how I prevent this from happening?

I using Dockerfile in my nestjs application

Does this also happen when you run nest outside a container? And if not, could you share your Dockerfile and docker-compose yaml?

Hi Diaz, I haven't tried it, but as I'm a junior dev, I only use docker, I'll show my dockerfile and docker compose, done

The volumes: block means you aren't actually running the code in your image at all: you're running whatever's checked out on the host system, plus whatever stale module tree happens to be in the named volume.  Does deleting that block make a difference?  I'd second @JesusDiazRivero's suggestion to try to reproduce this in a simpler environment that uses Node without Docker; it will be easier to debug not isolated in a container, and whatever you fix in a plain-Node environment should translate easily to the docker build image.

I deleted volumes but still dont work, I will try the 2 option, can you explain better for me? the 2 option
